# Largest Number in Array via Priority Queue and Break Out of Program?

Tags: java, arrays

The other day a recruiter asked me the following question:

> When asked to find the largest number in an array would you use sort or a for loop (keeping time efficiency of executing a priority on very large arrays). The program should end after finding the largest element, so nothing needs to be done with the array or elements after.

Am new to these type of coding puzzles (e.g. asking about priority on very large arrays) so my initial pass is this:

```java
public class Solution {
    public static int getLargestNumber(int[] array) {
        Arrays.sort(array);
        return array[array.length-1];
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```java
@Test
public void largestNumber() {
    int [] array = new int [] {17, 21, 3, 6, 9, 3, 15};
    int largestNumber = Solution.getLargestNumber(array);
    assertEquals(21, largestNumber);
}
```

Based on this question, however, is this seeking something else like a priority queue and what does it mean to end as soon as the largest number is obtained?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overthinking this - you can just do a simple one-pass for-loop over the array, store the max value, and then return it at the end:

```
public int getLargest(int[] arr)
{
  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    max = arr[i] > max ? arr[i] : max;
  }
  return max;
}
```

If I were doing this for an interview, I might also ask about edge cases like "what if the array is empty" or "do we need to extend this to other comparable data types, like strings"?  But for the scope of your question, something like this is fine.

Sorting and PriorityQueues are both non-ideal for this simple of an algorithm because both of them will run in O(nlog(n)) time, and potentially O(n) space as well.  A simple loop will run in O(n) time and O(1) space, which is much better.

Now, if you wanted to find the K largest numbers, then sorting or a PQ will be very appropriate.